# Running @Scheduled EJB method as particular user

Tags: java, ejb, schedule

I have a bean with scheduled method. The method calls another EJB's `refresh()` method which has @AroundInvoke interceptor on it. Interceptor in it's turn calls `sessionContext.getCallerPrincipal().getName()` to find out calling user and writes that info to database. When the same `refresh()` method is called through web-interface by logged in user everything is cool. But when scheduler calls the method I see 'anonymous' instead of real user name in database. How to run scheduled  method as particular user programmatically?

Comment: Which user do you expect the job to run as? Since its scheduled job its going to be anonymous. You will have to write some custom logic to handle this.

Comment: @6ton Each user in my project has a timer associated with him. I want a job to run as a user whose timer timed out and triggered a job execution.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for the [@RunAs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/819-3669/bncbh/index.html) annotation!  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914804/using-runas-in-my-ejb-schedulers) has an example of its use with schedulers.

Comment: @RunAs allows to specify role, not user. Besides I need scheduled method to run as the user whose timer was triggered.